# Setting jsessionid cookie secure in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, session-cookies, jsessionid

Even after adding below xml tag in tomcat, I still see the jsessionid cookie showing up as not secure in view cookie plugin in firefox, any suggestions on making it secure

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Did you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301636/weblogic-jsessionid-cookie-secure#23368126

Comment: In my case, I'm using tomcat

Comment: How did you overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try again by putting it in `Tomcat 7.0\conf\web.xml` file, search for `session-config` element, go there and add rest of values. It should work.